# Please tell me how to upgrade the QR code scanning recognition rate

Tags: java, android, zxing

I am developing using android studio and java and am a beginner developer.

It works by implementing zxing-android-embedded:4.3.0 in the app to scan the QR.

Depending on the angle, light, etc., there are many cases in which recognition is delayed.

Please tell me how to improve the recognition rate.

Please help.

<build.gragle>

```
implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.3.0'
```

<mainactivity.java>

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    scanCode();
}

private void scanCode(){
    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
    integrator.setCaptureActivity(CaptureAct.class);
    integrator.setOrientationLocked(false);
    integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
    integrator.addExtra(Intents.Scan.SCAN_TYPE, Intents.Scan.MIXED_SCAN);
    integrator.setPrompt("Code를 스캔해주세요.");
    integrator.initiateScan();
}
```

<CaptureAct.java>

```
package com.emtech.gscmapp;
import com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureActivity;
public class CaptureAct extends CaptureActivity {
}
```

ps. I am a beginner developer in Korea. If the translation is wrong, please understand.

sorry, thank you, Plz help me

Answer (score 0):

One way to improve the scan speed is to put the barcode format. This is if all barcode you'll be scanning are of the same format eg CODE 128, EAN_13

```
integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.CODE_128);
```